# Custom time in MYSQL on update

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table with some rows and within them there is a definition that goes like this:

```
  `metric_update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

So what i actually want it to do is to automatically insert a timestamp when inserting data into that table. And it does. But what I need is to write a GMT based time into that field (current server time is like GMT+2).

Is there a way to say to MYSQL to do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

If your server [time and timezone settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) are configured correctly, then internally **[all times stored in TIMESTAMP columns are converted to GMT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html)** (since that's what [Unix timestamp mandates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). They're converted back to your session timezone when you retrieve this data. If you want it presented in GMT timezone, you need to do conversion **while retrieving** data not while inserting.

See the console dump below for example. You can run these commands yourself to check.

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> -- let's create a table we'll be working with
mysql> CREATE TABLE tsTable (
    -> ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> -- let's check current time as well as timezone settings
mysql> SELECT CURTIME(),@@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| CURTIME() | @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| 16:25:51  | SYSTEM             | +02:00              |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> -- inserting empty row to table to trigger auto timestamp
mysql> INSERT INTO tsTable VALUES (null,null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- looks like the time in my local timezone is stored in table
mysql> SELECT * FROM tsTable;
+----+---------------------+
| ID | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2011-07-28 16:26:25 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- switching to GMT
mysql> SET SESSION time_zone = '+0:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- check current time and timezone settings again
mysql> SELECT CURTIME(),@@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| CURTIME() | @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| 14:27:53  | SYSTEM             | +00:00              |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- note: CURTIME() returns time two hours 'earlier' than before
mysql> -- let's see what's stored in the table again
mysql> SELECT * FROM tsTable;
+----+---------------------+
| ID | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2011-07-28 14:26:25 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- TIMESTAMP is two hours 'earlier' than before too! Magick!
```

Comment: This is just great info. I think Windows version treats time zones differently, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column1, metric_update_time) VALUES('dummy', CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+02:00','+03:00');
```

This will convert the inserted timestamp from `GMT+2` to `GMT+3`.

Comment: Ok i know that but can I define it like:
'metric_update_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+02:00','+03:00')',

Comment: @Igor Hrcek: Nope, you can't do that.